# TypeScript generic curried function with index type

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I have created a TypeScript curried function which first receives a property name as a string and then the object to get the value of that property from.
I have used index type to make sure I get an error whenever I try to access a non-existing property:

```
export interface Dict {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const prop = <T extends Dict, K extends keyof T>(p: K) => (obj: T): T[K] => obj[p];

prop('name')({name: 'John', age: 45});  // John
prop('name2')({name: 'John', age: 45});  // error...
```

The last line gives the error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"name2"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age"'.
```

which is exactly what I want since the property `name2` does not exist on the object given as the second argument.

However, when I try to create a safe version using a Maybe monad it gives a similar error:

```
const safeProp = <T extends Dict, K extends keyof T>(p: K) => (obj: T): Maybe<{}> => compose2(Maybe.of, prop(p))(obj);
```

The error is on the second argument of the `compose2` function: `prop(p)`:

```
Argument of type 'K' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age"'.
```

Which I don't understand since I have declared `K extends keyof T` which I assumed to be correct since it also works for the `prop` function.

For reference, the `compose2` function:

```
const compose2 = <A, B, C>(f: (b: B) => C, g: (a: A) => B): ((a: A) => C) => a => f(g(a));
```

and the relevant part of `Maybe` monad:

```
class Maybe<A> {
  static of<A>(x: A): Maybe<A> {
    return new Maybe(x);
  }

  ...
}
```

How do I correctly type the `safeProp` function and why do I need to specify its return type as `Maybe<{}>` and not `Maybe<T[K]>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [an issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366) detailing how Typescript doesn't correctly infer types when passing generic functions into generic higher order functions (in your case, that's passing `Maybe.of<A>` into `compose2<A,B,C>`).

You can alleviate this by manually filling in the types for `compose2` when using it.

```
const safeProp = <T extends Dict, K extends keyof T>(p: K) => (obj: T) => compose2<T, T[K], Maybe<T[K]>>(Maybe.of, prop(p))(obj);
```

`safeProp` now has the correct type `const safeProp: <T extends Dict, K extends keyof T>(p: K) => (obj: T) => Maybe<T[K]>`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I also added the return type for completeness:


`const safeProp3 = <T extends Dict, K extends keyof T>(p: K) => (obj: T): Maybe<T[K]> => compose2<T, T[K], Maybe<T[K]>>(Maybe.of, prop(p))(obj);`

Comment: A PR has recently been merged for TypeScript that maybe enable better inference for this situation in the future: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215

Comment: Great, thanks! I will have a good look tomorrow but I guess these are the propagated generic type arguments that will be in the coming TypeScript 3.4 release? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/

Answer (score 2):

```
const safeProp = <T extends Dict, K extends keyof Dict>(p: K) => (obj: T): Maybe<{}> => compose2(Maybe.of, prop(p))(obj);
```

The above code doesn't give you an error and I'll try to explain why (and why your code does).

`K extends keyof Dict` is exactly `name` or `age` (which are only allowed parameters for function `prop`). And
`K extends keyof T` can really be *any* key of type `number | string | Symbol`. Because if `T extends Dict`, it doesn't mean that it can't have any other keys like "lastname" etc. In other words:

```
type IsDict = {name: string, age: number, lastname: string} extends Dict ? true : false // IsDict is true
```

See? Your code would allow `lastname` key, and Typescript protects you from doing so.

That said, typescript currently [does not have](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) the means to restrict a type parameter to *exact* type (there are [workarounds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-448062329) but unfortunately they don't suit your case).

Comment: Good explanation, thanks a lot! I did however accept y2bd's answer since it is even more complete and allows to indicate the correct return type.

Comment: @DannyMoerkerke Ok, you are welcome! But didn't the problem be with `prop` function? I thought `Maybe` and stuff is irrelevant and the problem was `prop(p)` being error-highlighted.

Comment: Yes the main problem was with the `prop` function but like I said I was also wondering why the return type was `Maybe<{}>`.
Specifying the types for the `compose2` function explained it all for me.